# csv module writes time as decimal

Tags: python, excel, csv, xlrd

I am running into an issue where I have some data in a .xls file(example below).

```
  A            B           C         D         E        F
John Smith     8:00AM      9:00AM    10:00AM    5:00PM  8.00
```

When I write it to a csv using the Python CSV module it comes out as

```
John,Smith,0.333333333,0.375,0.416666667,0.708333333,0.333333333
```

Now the interesting part is if I manually save the xls file as a MSDOS csv I get the desired output of

```
John,Smith,8:00 AM,9:00 AM,10:00 AM,5:00 PM,8:00
```

Here is the function I am running. Its a bit messy so I apologize in advance.

```
def csv_gen(filepath, saveto):
    for files in glob.glob("*.xls"):
        shutil.copy(filepath + "\\" + files, saveto)
        with xlrd.open_workbook(files) as wb:
            sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
            newfile = saveto + files[:-4] + '.csv'
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            dates = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
            filestart = [saveto + files]
            time = [dates]
            with open(newfile, 'wb') as f:
                c = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
                list =  range(sh.nrows)
                last = range(sh.nrows)[-1]
                list.remove(0)
                list.remove(3)
                list.remove(2)
                list.remove(1)
                list.remove(last)
                #Iterate through data and show values of the rows
                for r in list:
                    lines = sh.row_values(r)
                    del lines[:4]
                    stuff = lines + filestart + time
                    #Remove blanks so csv doesnt have uneeded data
                    if lines[0] is '':
                        del stuff[:]
                    #Write to csv file with new data
                    if any(field.strip() for field in stuff):
                        c.writerow(stuff)
            shutil.move(newfile, mergeloc)
```

I don't understand why this is coming out this way. I have tried adding the dialect flag to the csv writer to be 'excel', but the output is still the same.

**Update:**

If I save the document as a csv as so `workBook.SaveAs(test.csv, 24)` The encoding 24 is for MSDOS. I get the desired output of

```
John,Smith,8:00 AM,9:00 AM,10:00 AM,5:00 PM,8:00
```

But when the csv module grabs it and removes some blank rows and deletes a few things at the end it writes the rows out and that is when I get the decimals again

```
John,Smith,0.333333333,0.375,0.416666667,0.708333333,0.333333333
```

The purpose of the csv module is to modify rows and delete blank rows.

**Update**

```
 for r in list: 
     cells = sh.row_values(r) 
     csv_row = cells[0] for col_value in cells[1:]:
         csv_row.append(datetime.time(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(col_value, 0)[3:]))
```

Added the row_values to just return the value of the cell and not xldata:0.33333. Then added a * to make the pass a positional argument.

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name.  It's quite confusing ...

Comment: Right, I am taking the xls and converting to a csv file. They are using this for tracking times of individuals then I am importing the data by csv file, because i need a delimited file

Comment: I tried to do this: `import datetime; now = datetime.datetime.now(); dates = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"); time = [dates]; print time` and I get `['11-13-2012']` is this what you expect to be in time?

Comment: Sorry, The  now = datetime.datetime.now()
        dates = now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") Is meant for later in the code to append another column with the date.

Comment: What does `print lines` output if you call it right after `lines = sh.row_values(r)`? What do you get from `sh.cell_type(0,1)` or what ever is the index of your first data row, hard to tell with you deleting some rows from the beginning of the sheet?

Comment: @thedemon So the question still remains whether the problem is the odd date representation of excel or the actual csv print out. What does `print sh.row_values(r)` output?

Comment: Doing a print as you suggested does give me the decimal output..                           ['', '', '', '', u'John', u'Smith', 0.333333333337, 0.7083333333333334, 0.3333333333333333]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look like a problem in `csv` module to me, it looks like something is going wrong in reading the `.xls` file.

According to the `xlrd` [docs](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html) dates in Excel worksheets are a pretty awful mess

> **Dates in Excel spreadsheets**
>
> In reality, there are no such things. What you have are floating point
>   numbers and pious hope. There are several problems with Excel dates:

I did a quick test with a new `.xls` file with the contents you provided in there. Python has no problems reading the file, although I don't have Excel on my machine, I made the file in LibreOffice and saved it as .xls. Even so, the fields come out as unicode strings on the python side.

You should be able to use the `xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(xldate, datemode)` ([link](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#xldate.xldate_as_tuple-function)) to convert the float into a python date tuple. Doing

```
print xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(0.333333333,0)
```

prints out

```
(0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0)
```

**UPDATE**

So you probably want something like the following, changing the `for` loop that goes over your rows

```
...
for r_idx in list:
    cells = sh.row(r)
    csv_row = [cells[0]] # the first row value should be ok as just a string
    for col_value in cells[1:]:
        # add the date time column values to the converted csv row
        csv_row.append( datetime.time(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(col_value, 0)[3:]) )
    ...
```

Comment: Hmm, So I went with what you suggested and stopped with a thought. If I save the document as a csv as so workBook.SaveAs(test.csv, 24) The encoding is for MSDOS. So when I check I have my desired output. Now when the csv module grabs it an removes some blank rows and deletes a few things at the end it writes the rows out and that is when i get the decimals again.

Comment: @thedemon well this probably should've gone in the original question. Maybe you should edit the question to contain the `thought`.

Comment: Ok I did do the above as this-a1 = sh.cell_value(rowx=4, colx=6)
   a1_as_datetime = datetime.time(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, 0)[3:]) On print I get 08:00:00 which is fine and works, but I am still a bit new to python. What would be the best way to iterate through the data and change the cells to get my desired results?

Comment: Thanks for the snippet I can see how that works. I did however make some changes and wanted to share for future reference and visitors. for r in list: cells = sh.row_values(r) csv_row = cells[0] for col_value in cells[1:]: csv_row.append(datetime.time(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(col_value, 0)[3:])) Added the row_values to just return the value of the cell and not xldata:0.33333. Then added a * to make the pass a positional argument.

Comment: @thedemon you should put the changes as an update to your question. No one will find them in the comment.